# Which Open Source GIS application support Linear Referencing and Dynamic Segmentation?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, linear-referencing, dynamic-segmentation

I'm looking for an Open Source GIS application that supports Linear Referencing and Dynamic Segmentation for the development of a road inventory system. I already know about GRASS but I'd like to know if there are any other options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other option that I have found is using [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/).  This software provides the spatial extensions for the [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) rdbms.  These are both Open Source.  There is a Linear Referencing Component described here:  [Link](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/reference.html#Linear_Referencing).

If you want to be able to access this functionality through a more full-featured GIS program, then you might use the [Linear Referencing](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/lrs) extension for [QGIS](http://qgis.org/).

You may load the plugin for QGIS through the Plugin Menu.  Use the Fetch Python Plugins command, then filter the search like the screenshot below:

[image]

Where the button currently shows "Reinstall", you will have the option to simply "Install" the plugin.

These are all open source products, and have active development, so I would say they are definitely worth checking out.